# Search WebView using findAllAsync() and findNext(true);

Tags: android, search, webview, highlight

I'm trying to search words in my webView. This is my method for search:

```
public void filterWebView(String query){

    if (query != null) {
        mQuery = query;
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                    view.findNext(true);
                    int c = view.findAll(mQuery);
                    try {
                        Method method = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                        method.invoke(view, true);
                    } catch (Throwable ignored) {}

                } else {
                    view.findNext(true);
                    view.findAllAsync(mQuery);

                    try {
                        Method method = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                        method.invoke(view, true);
                    } catch (Throwable ignored) {}
                }
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(mDocUrl);
    }
}
```

And it works great for API versions < 16, but for API 16 and >16 this method find all words, but  findNext() don't work.

If I set query and call this method 10 times in API <16 I get next result (if it exists) but in API >16 every time it highlights the same word.

What is wrong in second part of my method, after else{... ???

Comment: Where _setFindIsUp_ method should be?